# Riemann integral in Banach Spaces - Integration by parts

Tags: calculus, integration, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

I'm studying differential calculus in Banach spaces on my analysis course in specific Riemann integration in Banach Space some properties are extended but others I don't know how to start. Would anyone give me a hint to prove this result:

Let $Y$ a Banach Space, $f\colon[\alpha,\beta]\to Y$ and $g\colon [\alpha,\beta]\to \mathbb{R}$ continuous and differentiable maps. Prove that for each $a,b\in(\alpha,\beta)$, with $a<b$, then
$$\int_a^b Df(x)(t)g(t)+\int_a^b f(t)g'(t) = f(b)g(b)-f(a)g(a).$$

Additionally, can anyone recommend me some books about this topic?

Comment: Do you mean $Df(t)$? because the $x$ plays no role. If so, the LHS is simply $(fg)'(t)$, and now you just have to argue why for a $C^1$ function, the fundamental theorem of calculus continues to hold even when the target space is a general Banach space.

Comment: Actually, I don't know, I wrote this like  was in my lectures notes of my professor. Could you give any reference to find the original result?

Comment: Ok, I phrased it as a question because I suspected it was a typo. The correct statement is that $\int_a^bf'(t)g(t)+f(t)g'(t)\,dt = f(b)g(b)-f(a)g(a)$. Do you agree that the inside of the integral is $(fg)'(t)$ (it's literally the product rule, which is still true in the Banach space setting)? Now, I'm telling you to try to prove the (following special version of) Fundamental Theorem of Calculus: if $\phi:[a,b]\to Y$ is continuously differentiable then $\int_a^b\phi'(t)\,dt=\phi(b)-\phi(a)$.

Comment: Thanks, and could you help me with bibliography about this topic?